# How to send an HTTPS request through an On-Prem Data Gateway?

Tags: https, powerapps, client-certificates, onpremises-gateway

I setup an Azure Function locally as part of testing. I created a self-signed certificate and am able to send HTTP**S** GET requests to the Function via Postman. '

**Example**

[image]

I just setup an On-Prem Data Gateway. The install went smoothly and I can see the status as `Online` on `admin.powerplatform.com`...

[image]

I just created a PowerApps Custom Connector. The connector will send an HTTPS request to the Azure Function *once its published to Azure*. Until then, I want to test using the Function on localhost.

[image]

When I try to Test the Custom Connector, I receive a Status 500 and a WHOLE bunch of SSL error messages.

[image]

**Error:**

```html
<pre>
{
  "status": 500,
  "message": "Received error payload from gateway service with ID 340581: Substituted: HttpRequestException:<pi>System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.\r\n   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.GatewayHttpWebProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<<ProcessRequest>b__1>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.Metrics.QueryMetricUtils.<MeasureQueryOperationAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.GatewayHttpWebProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<ProcessRequest>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayPipelineTelemetry.PipelineTelemetryService.<ExecuteInActivity>d__7`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.GatewayProcessorDispatcher.<DispatchImpl>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.GatewayProcessorDispatcher.<Dispatch>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.Serialization.GatewayDeserializer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<Deserialize>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayPipelineTelemetry.PipelineTelemetryService.<ExecuteInActivity>d__7`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.Serialization.GatewayDeserializer.<Deserialize>d__8.MoveNext()</pi>.\r\nclientRequestId: 81139190-7a5a-4bff-b950-9fd36d680c0b",
  "error": {
"message": "Received error payload from gateway service with ID 340581: Substituted: HttpRequestException:<pi>System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.\r\n   at System.Net.TlsStream.EndWrite(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeadersCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)\r\n   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.GatewayHttpWebProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<<ProcessRequest>b__1>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.Metrics.QueryMetricUtils.<MeasureQueryOperationAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.GatewayHttpWebProcessor.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<ProcessRequest>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayPipelineTelemetry.PipelineTelemetryService.<ExecuteInActivity>d__7`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.GatewayProcessorDispatcher.<DispatchImpl>d__1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.GatewayProcessorDispatcher.<Dispatch>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.Serialization.GatewayDeserializer.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<Deserialize>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayPipelineTelemetry.PipelineTelemetryService.<ExecuteInActivity>d__7`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at Microsoft.PowerBI.DataMovement.Pipeline.GatewayCore.Serialization.GatewayDeserializer.<Deserialize>d__8.MoveNext()</pi>."
  },
  "source": "gatewayconnector-eus.azconn-eus-003.p.azurewebsites.net"
}
</pre>
```

**How do I send an HTTPS request from a Custom Connector to localhost?**

- With Postman, I provide the directory path to `certificate.pfx` and the password
- I don't see a way to send a certificate with the request in PowerApps

---

**Edit 1**

- Per @Jovin's advice, adding the self-signed cert to the Trusted Root Certification Authorities worked.
- Notes:

  - There was no "MMC" results when I looked. It was under "Managed Computer Certificates"
  - I protected the cert's private key with a very strong password and [set the `-NotAfter` date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pki/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=windowsserver2022-ps) to a minimal value required for testing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solutions worked for me on similar situation.

- Launch microsoft management console (MMC) on the machine where Gateway is setup and go to Certificates.
- Import the self-signed certificate in 'Trusted Root Certification
  Authorities' --> Certificates

Now if you test the custom-connector, then its expected to work.

Comment: This is helpful, thank you. I imagine the certificate should then be secured as if it was a PROD cert. I'll have to think through how to do that.

Comment: @SeaDude im facing the same issue could you please add more step by step guide to resolve this issue, thanks,